# How to go to the App Screen when "Swipe down for notification panel" is on?

Tags: home-screen, samsung-one-ui

On my Galaxy Note 10, how do I quickly go to the App screen when I enabled "Swipe down for notification panel" in the Settings Menue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, just swipe up, whereas when the "Swipe down for notification panel" feature is off swiping up AND down on the Home Screen enables the App Screen.